# VBA not setting cell text in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following line of code in my VBA code that I use to automatically set the text of a cell in an excel worksheet.

```
Sheets(checkout_sheet_name).Cells(Row_Index, checkout_tool_observation_column).Value = status
```

This same logic used to execute in my old spreadsheet just fine, but now I've transferred the module over to a new spreadsheet and it no longer works. The line executes with proper values for all the variables. Does anyone have any idea why this line of code would simply execute without actually setting the value of the cell to the text I see displayed in the debugger?

Thx.

Comment: are all your values what you expect them to be? (`checkout_sheet_name`, `Row_Index`, `checkout_tool_observation_column` and `status`)

Comment: With just that alone and the assumption that every variable has proper values, ...can you provide a bit more code? The new workbook has the same sheet names as the old working one? You mean it executes without giving you an error *and* without setting the cell value?

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code in that `Module`. The `Option Explicit` statement checks if all variables used in code have been declared (at the compilation time). It throws an error if they are not which makes it easier for the developer to check his code.

Comment: Also add a line `Debug.print Sheets(checkout_sheet_name).Cells(Row_Index, checkout_tool_observation_column).Value` and make sure the value is there. Sometimes it's a silly mistake having the font color set to white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the column I was writing to was collapsed somehow and one of the buttons I made would cover it when I tried to expand it. I'm not really sure why this happened, but when I transitioned my logic over to yet another new spreadsheet it went away.

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not know what comes before that line of code, you may want to debug.print the address of that cell and the status to support it did execute but no values set.

```
Debug.Print Now() & vbTab & Sheets(checkout_sheet_name).Cells(Row_Index, checkout_tool_observation_column).Address & " -> " & status
```